# SD card is recognized but won't mount "can't read superblock"

Tags: mount, filesystem, data-recovery, sd-card

When attempting to look at the files on my SD card I get the following message.

```
## Unable to access “16 GB Volume” ##
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/automat0n/6366-3430: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/mmcblk0p1" "/media/automat0n/6366-3430"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/mmcblk0p1: can't read superblock
```

The SD card is for my camera and when it's plugged into the camera I'm able to view all it's files and videos so I don't believe the SD is corrupted.

I'm currently running an analysis on testdisk but I'm uncertain what else I can do to get the files off the card. I'd rather not format the card and lose my data.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue. I think it has to do with -vfat. I was able to get the files off with Testdisk by removing it from `etc/fstab/` and finding it there. It seems to work sometimes mounting from nautilus.

Comment: Check the output of `dmesg` for more details, but it looks like the card is dead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before you try anything else, copy the entire device to a safe place:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/var/tmp/safeplace bs=1024k
```

If `dd` gives you errors, something may be wrong with your device, or the card reader in your machine. Have you tried reading it on some other machine (I assume the answer is "yes", so read on!)

Next, use try reading the partition table:

`sudo parted -l /dev/mmcblk0`

What is the partition type?

1. If it's vfat, maybe the superblock is corrupted; try `sudo fsck.vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1` (check the man page for options).
2. Did you actually create it on a linux machine? If not, maybe it's an exFAT filesystem. Try:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=16 count=1 | hd
   ```

   and see if the first few bytes are 'EXFAT'.  If so, install the fuse-based exfat:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse
   ```

   and try mounting manually if the GUI won't automatically recognize it.

If this still doesn't work, well, we'll have to dig deeper :)

Comment: I tried the command you recommended and tried to create an image and dd did infact give me an error                                                                             dd: error reading ‘/dev/mmcblk0p1’: Input/output error
It looks like it might be the card reader on my laptop thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error was looking like this:

```
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/severin/1885-EB0E:
  Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000...
```

(notice the `exfat` in the error message)

The fix was simple, like specified [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-this-Linux-Ubuntu-error-mounting-128GB-SD-Card-installing-exfat-utils):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Then, I just clicked the device in Nautilus, and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me using a microSD card in a USB adapter. The card was formatted for a GoPro, I have a Samsung RC512 running Ubuntu 14.04