# SD card is recognized but can't open it: “can't read superblock”

Tags: 16.04, sd-card

([Almost the same question but the solution proposed therein do not solve my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627829/sd-card-is-recognized-but-wont-mount-cant-read-superblock))

So I can mount the micro SD card but when I click on it I get:

```
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/me/NIKON D3100: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/mmcblk0p1" "/media/me/NIKON D3100"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/mmcblk0p1: can't read superblock
```

doing:

```
sudo parted -l /dev/mmcblk0
```

yields:

```
Model: SD SL16G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15,5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  15,5GB  15,5GB  primary  fat32        lba
```

(so it is fat32 but neither vfat nor exfat. It was formated by a photo camera).

How can I make my micro SD card ubuntu-usable

Answer (score -1):

First: if you need to save the data on the SD card make an image of the entire sd with dd before trying to fix it so you can always restore it later.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/home/sdCard.img
```

Then try to fix it with fsck.

```
sudo fsck /dev/mmcblk0
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link at the beginning. It's basically the same answer