# /var/tmp is going crazy with 43 GIGA BYTES OF STORAGE

Tags: 19.10

I have a lenovopad x270. I am running ubuntu 19.10. I am quite new to all of this so excuse me if this is basic. I am deleting the junk off of my laptop since I do not have that much space. 
After running:

```
ls /var/tmp


safeplace
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-bolt.service-Y1GTmg
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-colord.service-t2oPYe
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-fwupd.service-cPTgdi
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-ModemManager.service- 
pzeqxj
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-systemd- 
logind.service-zXM1Wg
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-systemd-resolved.service-4IR0Jh
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-systemd- 
timesyncd.service-ueabej
systemd-private-8783bc55275541e49de4244599caab99-upower.service-sk73oi
```

Why is this taking 43 giga bytes and can I delete them? Also, what is safeplace?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question ([edit]) and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What creates temporary files can vary on what software you have installed, let alone how you use it (config file choices etc). Currently your question is rather vague (I have some of those like-type files on my system, but they aren't very big measuring MB only)

Comment: Thank you, I just did.

Comment: The systemd dirs should all be EMPTY. Are they?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any software using the file `/var/tmp/safeplace`.

But it is used in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/627855/2369) to backup a SD card. If you remember doing something like this and you don't need the backup any more you may safely delete the file.